# Problema JavaScript en navegador web de móvil SAMSUNG

Tags: javascript, imagen

Tengo un problema al cargar mi página web en dispositivos móviles.
Con el navegador de web Chrome todo funciona correctamente, pero al cargarla con el navegador por defecto de Samsung (el internet de la bola del mundo), no se me ejecuta el código javascript que despliega el menú responsive. Aparte las imágenes de la ficha de producto tampoco se cargan. Es raro porque como digo, en el navegador de Chrome todo funciona correctamente. Me preocupa debido a que muchos usuarios con teléfonos Samsung utilizan este navegador y al acceder a la página no funcionan estos elementos.
Adjunto el código que despliega el menú (cambia la clase CSS de este)

```
$menuToggle.click(function() {
    $menu.toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Estas usando jQuery como veo, has cargado el script de jQuery.mobile?

Comment: Mira a ver si el navegador que viene por defecto en android soporta javascript o si está deshabilitado.

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo.. y no se que hacer porque no me funciona el click touchstart

Answer (score 1):

para que podamos ayudarte hace falta mas información. Que versión de jQuery estas usando? estas usando jQuery mobile? que contiene la variable $menuToggle?, que contiene la variable $menu? Siempre es mejor hacer un fiddle así la gente que trata de ayudarte pueda reproducir tu problema. De todas formas, voy a tratar de adivinar el problema, me parece que estas usando el evento click en un elemento que no es anchor.

**El problema**

Los eventos click no existen en el telefono, ya que solo hay "touch", no tenemos un mouse, entonces los telefonos "emulan" los clicks. Según vemos en este articulo: https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html (ingles) que por problemas de memoria, los eventos click estan limitados a anchor e input. PERO podemos usar eventos touch para mobiles.

**Eventos touch**

**touchstart:** Este se genera al hacer cualquier toque a la pantalla, sin importar su duración o movimientos realizados.

**touchend:** Este se ejecuta una vez se deja de tocar la pantalla o el objeto que tiene asignado el manejador de eventos.

**touchmove:** Este es ejecutado una vez se desliza o desplaza el dedo el usuario, por encima de la pantalla u objeto que está siendo controlado a través del manejador de eventos.
Info sacada de: https://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/eventos-touch-javascript.html

**Solución:**

```
$menuToggle.on('click touchstart', function() {
    $menu.toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Info similar en esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015908/onclick-not-working-on-mobile-touch

Comment: Hola gracias por responder. Estoy usando jquery-1.12.0 como versión de jquery. No empleo jquery mobile. La variable **$menu** contiene la clase **.menu**, la cual comprende el menú en sí `<nav class="menu">`. La variable **$menuToggle** contiene la clase **.menu-toggle**, la cual comprende el div con el icono del menu `<div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></div>`. La función desplega o no el menú al pinchar en el icono. He probado con _touchstart_, pero sigue sin funcionar. Lo raro es que en el navegador de chrome de móvil funciona sin problemas. Falla en el navegador de Samsung.

Comment: Me pasa exactamente el mismo problema, ya que uso eventos click , y key , pero en los navegadores de los moviles no funcionan, intentare usar el evento Touch a ver ,aunque me tocaria dejar cada pagina independiente , es decir una para web y otra para moviles